# Java RestTemplate response mapping with nested list of objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

Hi I am hitting an endpoint with rest template and getting the response. 
When I use String as return type and print the response it's an XML response with multiple tags.
and when I use Object as return type then RestTemplate is mapping only last tag from the list.

**With String.class as return type**
*Request:*

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(urlTemplate, httpEntity, String.class);
System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

*Response:*

```
<Order>
    <OrderLines>
        <OrderLine LineID="1"></OrderLine>
        <OrderLine LineID="2"></OrderLine>
        <OrderLine LineID="3"></OrderLine>
    </OrderLines>
</Order>
```

**With Object.class as return type**
*Request:*

```
ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(urlTemplate, httpEntity, Object.class);

System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

*Response:*

```
{
    "OrderLines": {
        "OrderLine": {
            "LineID": "3"
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected Response with Object.class as return type is:**

```
{
    "OrderLines": {
        "OrderLine": [
            {
                "LineID": "1"
            },
            {
                "LineID": "2"
            },
            {
                "LineID": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Please suggest the solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model class to Map the expected Response with Object.class as return type, But instant you will need to have it like OrderLines.class ( which is your newly created model )

Then you can use ObjectMapper or Gson to map the response like the following.

```
OrderLines obj = gson.fromJson(stringResponse, OrderLines.class); 
return obj;
```

This will have the created model object to be returned after getting the information needed from the string returned type.